# error with aiter in telethon bot in python

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telethon

i'm trying to loop inside my async function for my bot, and for the autodestruction function i have to iterate all the users and check if the user is an admin, done with this code:

```
all_participants = await bot.get_participants(group, aggressive=False)
    admins = bot.iter_participants(group, filter=ChannelParticipantsAdmins)
    print('[+] Banno gli utenti...')
    async for user in all_participants:
        if not user in admins:
            pass
```

The issue comes when i try to run my code, returning this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elias/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/updates.py", line 467, in _dispatch_update
    await callback(event)
  File "bannerbot.py", line 31, in pyro
    async for user in all_participants:
TypeError: 'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got TotalList
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

`get_participants` returns a list, not an async iterator:

```
all_participants = await bot.get_participants(group, aggressive=False)
admins = await bot.get_participants(group, filter=ChannelParticipantsAdmins)
#                  ^^^ get, not iter
print('[+] Banno gli utenti...')
for user in all_participants:
# ^ removed the async
    if not user in admins:
        pass
```

However this still won't work because the `user` and `admins` objects are probably different. You should look for `admins` by comparing the `id`, not the entire `user` object.